# Estimation of a function - contour integration

Tags: complex-analysis

I was trying to understand how to solve integrals featuring rational functions using residue theory from Gamelin's Complex analysis.

Question is to evaluate $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}$$

Explanation given in the book is as follows :

Let $D_R$ be the half disk in the upper half place bounded by the interval $[-R,R]$ on the real axis and the semicircular contour $\Gamma_R$ of radius $R$ on the upper half plane.

Then it says that on $\Gamma_R$ we have $$\left|\frac{1}{1+z^2}\right|\leq \frac{1}{R^2-1}$$

I fail to see why this is true.. On $\Gamma_R$ we have $|z|=R$

$$\left|z^2+1\right|=\left|z+i\right|\left|z-i\right|\geq (\left|z+i\right|)(\left|z\right|-\left|i\right|)=(\left|z+i\right|)(R-1)$$

We want $$\left|\frac{1}{1+z^2}\right|\leq \frac{1}{R^2-1}$$ i.e., we must have $|z+i|\geq R+1$ but this need not be true.. :O

I am confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is the estimate $$|z^2 + 1| \ge |z^2| - |1| = R^2 - 1.$$

Comment: Thanks but are you saying $|a+b|\geq |a|-|b|$ always?

Comment: Yes, since $|a| = |(a+b) - b| \le |a+b| + |-b|$